# What is the name of this problem about queuing processes?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, queueing-theory

The problem is: suppose we have $p$ processes labeled $1, \ldots, p$, with runtimes $(t_1, \ldots, t_p) \in \mathbb{R}_{++}^p$. In what order should the processes be set up to minimize overall runtime if $n < p$ processes can run concurrently?

My first thought was that decreasing order is optimal, but there are simple counterexamples. After thinking about it, I think this problem is isomorphic to this problem: given a collection of $p$ straws of various length, how can you arrange the straws in $n < p$ lines to minimize the length of the largest line?

In that sense, if the lines all have the same length, you have a perfect ordering (where the process queues have 100% usage time). I've tried to google it, but I can't seem to find anything. So:

1) Is this a well-known problem? I would think it must be.

2) Does it have a known solution?

3) Is it underdetermined as written?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I believe this is the [job shop scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. If you propose that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an instance of the [job shop scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling). Specifically, with atomic jobs.